# Call a Form method from a different thread (Invoke)

Tags: multithreading, winforms, c++-cli, invoke

I've got a WinForm running on my main thread and a `while(true)` loop running on a separate thread. Each loop of that `while(true)` creates a new `System::String^` and I want to paste that `String` into a `TextBox` on my UI.

My file structure includes `GUI.h`, `GUI.cpp`, and `Other.cpp`.

`GUI.h` contains all the automatically created code for the main (and only) Form. It also has some `Get`, `Set`, and `ButtonClick` methods.

```
//GUI.h
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cliext\vector>
#include <conio.h>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

extern void BufferRecieveLoop();

namespace GUI_Example_Receive { 

    static bool loopFlag = true;

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::Threading;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for GUI
    /// </summary>
    public ref class GUI : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        GUI(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        std::vector<std::string> CollectText();
        void ContinueNormally(); // Object^);
        void DisableAllTextboxes();
        void EnableAllTextboxes();

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~GUI()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    private:
        //Labels
        //GroupBoxes
        //Buttons
        //SaveFile

    public:
        //TextBoxes
        System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  consoleTextBox;

    private:
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            //automatically made, lightly edited
        }
#pragma endregion

    public: 
        void SetConsoleTextBoxText(System::String^ input)
        {
            this->consoleTextBox->Text = input;
            this->consoleTextBox->Refresh();
        }

        void ClearConsoleTextBoxText()
        {
            this->consoleTextBox->Clear();
        }

        delegate void MyDelegate(System::String ^ str);

        void ClearAndSetConsoleTextBoxText(System::String ^ input)
        {
            /***************************************************
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                this->BeginInvoke(gcnew MyDelegate(this, &ClearAndSetConsoleTextBoxText), { input });
            }
            ***************************************************/
            ClearConsoleTextBoxText();
            SetConsoleTextBoxText(input);
        }

        System::Void startButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
        {
            loopFlag = true; //able to loop through ContinueNormally()

            ContinueNormally(); //method in GUI.cpp
        }

    };

    //https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4da834f0-d8f8-4abb-a655-ef9e99d51eb2/how-to-create-a-global-object-of-a-ref-class-type?forum=vcgeneral
    ref struct Globals {
        static GUI ^gui; //using Globals::gui everywhere to access the one Form
    };

}
```

`Gui.cpp` contains code to `Run()` the form, start a thread, and loop forever.

```
//GUI.cpp
void BufferRecieveLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        size_t bytes_read = multicast.Receive(buffer, Example::MTU_SIZE);

        incoming.Process(buffer, bytes_read, endian); //method in Other.cpp
    }
}

void GUI::ContinueNormally()
{
    System::Threading::Thread ^loopThread = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(BufferRecieveLoop));
    loopThread->Start();
    loopThread->Join();
}

static void Start()
{
    Globals::gui = gcnew GUI;
    System::Windows::Forms::Application::Run(Globals::gui);
}

int __cdecl main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    System::Windows::Forms::Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    System::Windows::Forms::Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Start();

    return 0;
}
```

`Other.cpp` creates a `String^` and calls a method within `GUI.h` to change the text in a textbox.

```
//Other.cpp
void Process(const DIS::Pdu& packet)
{
    System::String^ sysStr2 = "stuff";

    GUI_Example_Receive::Globals::gui->ClearAndSetConsoleTextBoxText(sysStr2);

    //GUI_Example_Receive::Globals::gui->BeginInvoke(gcnew MyStringDelegate(GUI_Example_Receive::Globals::gui, &GUI_Example_Receive::GUI::ClearAndSetConsoleTextBoxText), { sysStr2 });
}
```

I don't know where to properly `Invoke` my methods. Nor do I know *how* to `Invoke` my methods. A lot of what I've found is C# and hasn't worked for me.

Do I invoke from `Other.cpp` or inside the method being called in `GUI.h`?

Comment: I don't see any synchronization or atomics. How is this possibly thread safe?

Comment: @JesperJuhl This is the only thread calling back to the only form `Globals::gui`. There wouldn't be any race conditions as far as I know.

Comment: Looks to me you know where to invoke just fine.  The code is just not correct.  The two statements after the comment belong in an else-block.  Right now the debugger is going to tell you that the code is wrong, breaking on the InvalidOperationException.  The kind of essential detail you must *always* mention in a question.  Realistically you should not use InvokeRequired at all, you know you always have to invoke.

Comment: @HansPassant Everything I've seen has had some sort of check with `if(InvokeRequired)`, though you are correct and it's not really needed. The error is not coming up for me. When debugging, I reach a regular method within `GUI.h` like `SetConsoleTextBoxText()` and it will simply stop debugging **without giving me an error**.

I appreciate you letting me know that I'm doing the `Invoking` in the correct spot, now just to get the actually correct code to do so.

Comment: `this->BeginInvoke(gcnew MyDelegate(this, &ClearAndSetConsoleTextBoxText), { input });` is giving me "illegal operation on bound member function expression" and "invalid argument for delegate constructor; delegate target needs to be a pointer to a member function" errors.  Small specific issues are all that remain; I don't know how to fix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has issues with this in the future and, like me, doesn't find many c++ code examples, I'll post my solution.

In my `GUI.h` file, I've got a method to `SetConsoleTextBoxText()`. This is usable only by the thread which owns `consoleTextBox`. Therefore, any other thread which trys to call that method will need to `Invoke()` the method (which is to relinquish control back to the owning thread).

```
//GUI.h
delegate void MyDelegate(System::String ^ text);

void SetConsoleTextBoxText(System::String^ input)
{
    if (this->consoleTextBox->InvokeRequired) //is a thread other than the owner trying to access?
    {
        MyDelegate^ myD = gcnew MyDelegate(this, &GUI::SetConsoleTextBoxText); 
        //GUI is the ref class. Replace with wherever your function is located.
        this->Invoke(myD, gcnew array<Object^> { input }); //Invoke the method recursively
    }
    else
    {
        //Normal function of this method. This will be hit after a recursive call or from the owning thread
        this->consoleTextBox->Text = input;
        this->consoleTextBox->Refresh();
    }
}
```